# Open a url site in a WinForms window and not from the browser

Tags: c#, winforms, url

I have a C# WinForms application which I need to open a url through it.

The actual task is to display a web page without all it's functionality (changing url/go back button/etc...), do some actions in that site and then retrieve information from it according to what the user entered/did in that site.

Iv'e already tried the WebBrowser option, but it's opening the url site in a browser with all of it's functionality:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WebBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
WebBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766190/open-a-url-site-in-a-winforms-window-and-not-from-the-browser"), true);
WebBrowser1.BringToFront();
```

Any ideas?

Thanx :)

Comment: "_Iv'e already tried the WebBrowser option, but it's opening the url site in a browser with all of it's functionality..._" Can you [edit] your question and add the code you're using? That doesn't sound like it's using the WebBrowser control at all.

Comment: Sorry, but I checked that with the WebBrowser Control: You have ONLY the browser window, no menu system or other features of a browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "no menu system or other features of a browser"? It's actually opening the default web browser so I have all of it's functionality

Comment: What default web browser are you talking about? Do you mean chrome, IE or what exactly?

Comment: You're passing `true` as the second argument to the `Navigate()` method, which specifies that it should open in a new window - [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Navigate_System_Uri_System_Boolean_)

Comment: You have to add `WebBrowser1` to `this.Controls()` to actually see it. As of now, your WebBrowser is never shown and you're opening an instance of the default Browser.

Comment: It opened inside a IE browser, but I don't want all of the browser functionality as I said, even if it opened in the same/different window - it's not a problem

Comment: It's not clear what your requirement is. Please elaborate more about what user should be able to do with the browsed page and what they shouldn't be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `true` as the second argument to the `Navigate(Uri url, bool newWindow)` method, which specifies that it should open the url in a new window (see the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_Navigate_System_Uri_System_Boolean_)).

Changing your code so that it passes `false` for the `newWindow` argument will cause the url to be opened in the WebBrowser control instead (you also need to add the control to the form's `Controls` collection):

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser WebBrowser1 = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
this.Controls.Add(WebBrowser1);
WebBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766190/open-a-url-site-in-a-winforms-window-and-not-from-the-browser"), false);
```